# Adding a role to an opsworks instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, roles, aws-opsworks, amazon-iam

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to change an OpsWorks role of a running stack (without having to clone the entire stack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the role in the stack settings, but the instances you have created up to now will still have the old role. Any new instances you create after that will have the new role.

Opsworks or not, once an instance is assigned a role, it cannot be changed, you can only create a new instance with a different role.

The role policies can be changed any time though, so if you need to make changes, you can just attach a new policy to an existing role rather than creating a new role.